# Is there a respectful way to address a Catholic priest other than "Father"?

Tags: catholicism, priests, father, etiquette

Many Protestants object to the practice of addressing priests as "Father," citing Matthew 23:9.

> And call no man your father upon the earth: for one is your Father, which is in heaven.

Is there a respectful way for someone who is not Catholic to address a priest other than calling him "Father"?

Comment: As a related note, refusing to address someone based upon what is customary for that person in their society/culture and how they are accustomed to be address may come off as disrespectful or rude or worse denigrating of their role or theology.

Comment: @eques  Is this not really a matter of personal conscience, for individuals? A person who wishes to keep their conscience clear before God by heeding Jesus' instruction not to use the title 'Father' in a religious sense, is not swayed by custom or culture, especially if most people in their country (even unbelievers) use it automatically. They will be moved by how they believe God views the matter, so using a different but respectful form of address should not be taken as denigrating anyone or anything.

Comment: @Anne my point is twofold, one generic, one more specific. The generic one is the norm of human society. If you call someone Mister despite that person being a doctorate-holding professional, in many causes that would be seen by that person and others as treating them with disrespect and/or contempt. The more specific case would be the religious one, which incidentally my earlier comment only implied. I didn't quite say thou shall not, but pointed out how it may be perceived. It's your choice whether that perception is "worth it."

Comment: @Anne this question is tagged Catholicism despite pointing out a concern some Protestants may have. However, "heeding Jesus' instruction not to use the title 'Father' in a religious sense" is fundamentally not a Catholic position (as seen elsewhere) so Catholicism does not provide an answer to assuage the Protestant concerns. "using a different but respectful form of address should not be taken as denigrating anyone" That may be an ideal, yet that doesn't mean it works in practice. A priest hopefully is humble enough to not make a fuss but how it is perceived is a separate concern.

Comment: @eques I tagged the question as [catholicism] because it's asking if there's another term used in Catholicism. I did not tag it as [protestant] because while the reason for asking is based on Protestant beliefs, the question isn't actually about Protestantism. If there's another religious group that objects to the Catholic use of the word "father," this would be equally relevant to them.

Comment: @Someone understandable, however the label's description is specifically "about Catholicism, its teachings and practices" not what Protestantism does in relation to it nor how does Catholicism accommodate views which conflict with its own (well perhaps indirectly).

Comment: @eques : demanding that I address someone in a way which is contrary to my beliefs is also disrespectful and rude. If I demanded you to call me "mylord", would you comply? I could point out some ancestors of mine, which in my culture were addressed like that, so I could demand that from you if I wanted to be a prick.

Comment: @eques  That is why I won't answer this Q; I'm not a Catholic, nor do I know the answer to the Q. But your 1st comment could equally apply to Catholics who, for conscience' sake, will not address their religious leaders as 'Father'. There might not be many of them around, but who knows whether some who use 'padre' or 'monsignor' etc chose that over 'Father'? We cannot (and should not) judge anyone on such a personal matter

Comment: I think that fairer to say that "some" protestants take this position.  Saying "many" protestants is a bit misleading because it gives the impression that this is a common position in Protestantism when it is in fact rather uncommon, even among us protestants.  I know thousands of protestants and very few take this position and most would say that reading it this literally would meant that we could not call our own fathers "father" and we do do that pretty consistently.

Comment: Don't you think that since so many Protestants have been objecting to that for hundreds of years, most Protestant churches made their views clear almost equally long ago?

Cn you say which part of which church's view doesn't work for you?

Comment: @vsz I didn't say "demand", did I? And the actual question would be by what custom or right the person expected to be called "my lord". If they were an actual noble in a monarchical nation, I wouldn't object. If they desired to be called "my lord" out of their own personal ego, that's a different matter.

Comment: @Anne It would be more likely that a cleric with the title of Monsignor prefers to be called Father, than the other way around. Yet, Catholics refusing to use Father based upon "conscience" would be in a problematic area since that implies they are holding to an interpretation of Scripture the Church has never taught.

Comment: @eques  That, indeed, would be a problematic area for them.

Comment: Consider that in the beginning of 1 Timothy and Titus, Paul addresses each one as "my son in the faith."  If Timothy and Titus were Paul's sons in the faith, then Paul must have been their...what?...in the faith?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Is there a respectful way to address a Catholic priest other than "Father"?**

Military clergy, both Catholic or otherwise (Protestant or Jewish) are often called Padre. In Portuguese, priests are called **“padre”**, which is not the same word for a father, “pai”. As a matter of fact, the Portuguese word “padre” is only used for priests, having no other use. Granted, in archaic Portuguese it was used for father too.

The term **Dom**, is used for bishops and religious priest of the Benedictine Order.

I know a few religious (Religious Order) priests who are called **Brother**.

Some priests are called **Monsignor**, if they have been accorded that title.

Italian priests are called **Don**.

If you are really uneasy about it, I would imagine that the simple term of **Reverend**, would be appropriate. Do not think any priest would object to this phrase being employed.

Pope John Paul II as a young priest, asked his young friends to call him [**”wujek”**](http://www.papalartifacts.com/the-wujek-letters-of-st-john-paul-ii-on-papal-artifacts/), which is Polish for **uncle**. In this way, the Communists would not know a priest was in the mist of the group and could freely administer the sacraments!

There are also Lutherans who call their pastors "priests" and "fathers." This is especially true in European countries.

Still have to chuckle a little about this as no one feels uneasy about calling the [***Founding Father of the United States***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Founding_Fathers_of_the_United_States) anything else than the **Founding Fathers**!

Dads do not mind being called father by their children. And professors are still called teachers!

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149938/discussion-on-answer-by-ken-graham-is-there-a-respectful-way-to-address-a-cathol); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: In Romanian, an Orthodox priest is addressed as _părinte_, which means "parent" rather than "father."

Answer (score 5):

In my country, translated to English, it is very rare to call a priest “Father”. If any special title is being used, “reverend” is most common if combined with a name, or “mister pastor” if no name is used. Deacons are called the same, unfortunately as a deacon cannot be a pastor here.

Comment: Deacons can never be pastors (parochus/parish priest) in Catholicism

Comment: I believe you. I can only speak for the languages I know. In my language a pastor is a priest. So not a deacon, as I said.

Comment: We seem to be saying more or less the same thing, but some terminology appears to be getting conflated. "as a deacon cannot be a pastor here" would imply in English that some other place/location as deacon could be a pastor, but as you agree as pastor is a priest.

Comment: Ah, yes, I think we say the same thing. My apologies for any linguistical mistakes!

Answer (score 2):

In Latin the vocative ***domne*** (lowercase "d" and lack of "i"), "**O lord**", is one way to address a priest; *Domine* (capital "D" and with an "i"), "O Lord", is reserved for God alone.

- Joseph A. Jungmann, *[The Mass of the Roman Rite: Its Origins and Development (Missarum Sollemnia)](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=4997)*, trans. Francis Brunner, vol. 1 (New York: Benziger Brothers, 1951), 454 & 455n94:

> The *domnus* here [in asking a priest "[*Iube, domne, benedicere.*](https://www.ccwatershed.org/2021/02/21/the-liturgical-request-iube-domne-benedicere/)", "Deign, lord, to give a blessing."] used is also customary in other cases to distinguish earthly masters from the heavenly *Dominus*.

Comment: Are you aware of this term being used outside of liturgical ceremony?

Comment: @eques No, I'm not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with many titles is that they not only designate someone's position, they also indicate a relationship with the person that says the title.

For instance "bishop", "elder", "priest", "senator", "rabbi", "monk", and even "patriarch" should be acceptable to everyone.

But while titles like "father", "milord", "brother", "pope", "abbot", and "monsignor" are fine for members of their own church,
many other people would feel uncomfortable using those titles to address someone.

I don't want to address anyone as "my lord" or "father" unless they really *are* my lord or my father.

Saying "your eminence", "your reverence", or "your highness" provides some distance, acknowledging the position without implying that the position is with respect to oneself.

For references that aren't directly addressing the person, sometimes "the" can be inserted.
Saying "the father" or "the pope" merely indicates that you recognize what they are without implying a relationship to oneself.

And if it doesn't feel too awkward, one might even speak directly to someone in the third person.
"*Would the Father like another piece of cake?*"
"*The Monsignor is very amusing tonight.*"

Comment: The division of titles into two categories seems entirely arbitrary; several in the former are relational in origin and some in the latter while they originate from relational terms are used to such a degree that the relational aspect is far from explicit. Adding "the" is sometimes used, possibly without the effect described/intended. Speaking in the 3rd person is done with styles (Your Excellency) but would seem odd for the examples given, especially since using the 2nd person in those implied cases would be more natural and avoid the issue discussed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an analogy: A person who doesn't recognize a US president's election would still address them as "President so-and-so" unless they wanted to be rude about it. In the case "Father so-and-so," the term "Father" is a title bestowed by the Roman Catholic Church, not a personal appellation.

As long as you follow the title with a personal name ("Father Patrick" for example) you are not actually calling the person "Father" but merely using his ecclesiastical title. If one feels conscience-bound to avoid the term, try "Reverend." It's off-putting, but not exactly rude.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not interesting to note that Jesus himself called his Father ' Abba' which roughly translates to Daddy ?In the Liturgy of Catholic Church involving different Rites, wherever there is a reference to the celebrant, he is referred to as The Priest. In fact the vocative noun Father seems to be of recent origin . Catholic priests of Southern India were addressed as Kassieessa in Syriac and Kathanar,  root of the latter being unknown. It was only after the arrival of the English that priests started getting addressed as Father . The counterpart word of the local language  for 'biological father' is used with a different set of spelling and diction so as to bring in specific identity.
PS: If calling a priest 'Father'is against Mtt 23:9, calling a Bishop  'My Lordship' is also not proper since the First Commandment says " I am the Lord your God.."